# How do I add an authentication header to a GitHub webhook

Tags: github

I have built a Service in Salesforce which I am passing in as payload URL to my GitHub Webhook. Invoking this service needs a Authorization header (Bearer "access_token").

Currently when I have set up this webhook in GitHub and it tries to push the events, it's encountering 401 Unauthorized (as it doesn't have the Authorization Header set)

Can anyone tell how do I set the Authorization header when configuring my webhooks?

Comment: Can you provide an example without posting your credentials?

Comment: @osowskit
https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GitHubServ is the kind of end point I'm trying to configure as payload URL. While invoking this service endpoint there has to be an Authorization header which is like

Authorization : Bearer "access_token".

access_token is a alphanumeric string generated during login.

Comment: It sounds like you need a server/job running outside of either Salesforce or GitHub that listens for GitHub webhooks events and calls your API endpoint in SalesForce.

Comment: @osowskit Yeah that's the work around I have to go for but wanted to explore if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround on the Salesforce Side.

I found an older post on this subject https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

It appears you can expose your Apex Rest enabled class using Sites.

Once you have a site:

1. Edit your site details.
2. Click Public Access Settings.
3. Go to Apex Class Access and then add the class.

I had a test community created, and have used Sites settings to enable it there.